# rendering charts in component

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have several diagrams. When switching from one component to another, an error occurs, or when I switch to the business section.
Also this error occurs when on one component and simply switch businesses

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')

What am I doing wrong? Please help. I used Chartjs

```
export class ActivityReportComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isLoading = false;
  private chart: Chart | null = null;
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private reportCenterService: ReportCenterService,
    private userService: UserServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.currentBusinessId$.subscribe(businessId => {
      this.getReport();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.clear();
      this.chart.destroy();
    }
  }

  getReport() {
    this.isLoading = true;
     this.subscription = this.reportCenterService.getActivityReport().subscribe((res: any) => {
      const ctx: any = document.getElementById('dailyActivityChart');
      const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
      const networks = Object.keys(res.data[days[0]]);
      const datasets = networks.map(network => {
        const data = days.map(day => res.data[day][network]);
        return {
          label: network,
          data: data,
          borderWidth: 3
        };
      });

      if (this.chart) {
        this.chart.clear();
        this.chart.destroy();
      }

      this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: days,
          datasets: datasets
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        }
      });
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your view is not loaded before you try to render the chart. Can you try to run getReports in ngAfterViewInit.